# Getting response of http request without content-length?

Tags: http, tcp, http-headers

I have a little program sends http request and gets response with TCP protocol.

My request format;

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: somewebsite.com
{two new line}
```

I read response line by line from socket (using NetworkStream and StreamReader in c#) until I find content-length header. I store the length, then continue reading until find an empty line. Then create a buffer with the length and receive the rest of response.

But some reponses does not have a content-length header. So my approach fails. If I don't know how many bytes I should receive, when I should stop?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In `HTTP/1.0` - server response without `content-length` is when the stream closes

In `HTTP/1.1` - server response without `content-length` is when the response is [chunked encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: Based on the other answer is appears that HTTP/1.1 servers can still do it by closing the stream...

Comment: @rogerdpack yes, it can, but it doesn't need to anymore

Comment: This is not true: in HTTP/1.1, without content-length is not necessary chunked. It is chunked if the Transfer-Encoding header field says so. It there is no Transfer-Encoding header field, then the client should receive all data until the server to actually close the connection. Please check the https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3 point 7.

Answer (score 10):

See [relevant part of HTTP spec](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#message.length).
In your specific case, if the server does not give content length back, then it MUST be closing the stream upon finishing the response. There is no other reliable way for you (as a client) to know. Regardless of HTTP version. @Julian chunked encoding is indeed a clever upgrade in HTTP/1.1 but is rather specific to streaming and there is no reason why a "plain" webserver would implement it. That is a server which knows the content length before initiating response. And i guess that the OP doesn't have the server under control, otherwise he won't be objecting missing HTTP headers.

But even if you DO get the content length header, you [must not unreservedly trust it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_Principle). The server implementors are only fallible humans too. Take it as a "most probable" response, initial value to a resizable buffer. You still must be ready to handle less as well as more (the worse case).

Comment: That is very misleading. If the response has a content-length header field and doesn't use chunked encoding, that is the *only* information you have. If you receive less content, the content should be considered truncated. If you receive more content, the serer is broken, or you're already looking at the next response.

Comment: I am humbly asking for explanation how reading the next response could happen on a single unique socket, when the client didn't finish parsing the current one yet so it very unlikely sent the next request already. I may understand the downvote better. Otherwise i don't see any significant disagreement on the matter. What would you do when you read up to the declared content length and socket read tells you there is 2 more bytes left? In reality, saying "stupid broken server, i won't talk to you anymore" is not applicable as often as good programmers would like to.

Comment: vtmarvin: the client could use pipelining.

Comment: Ah pipelining, ok. I almost got astonished that there is some mysterious HTTP feature that allows server to send multiple responses to a single request, which is what OP is most probably wanting to do.