# How to determine last packet on http non-persistent connections

Tags: apache, security, http, web, https

I am some kind of a Gateway between the client and server, meaning that i can see all traffic passing between them.
Now, a non-persistent HTTP connection is established between the server and the client, the client sends a HTTP request and the server responses with a 200 OK and a file, the response doesn't contain the `Content-Length` header(this is ok since this is a non-persistent connection).
I, as the Gateway between them, want to know when the last packet is sent from the server before it reaches the client,Meaning, Waiting for the connection to close is not good for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting response of http request without content-length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375507/getting-response-of-http-request-without-content-length)

Answer (score 0):

If the HTTP/1.1 connection is not persistent (i.e. the `Connection` header is *not* set to `keep-alive`), and for all HTTP/1.0 connections, the connection is closed once the transfer has completed.

That is, the server closes the connection in order to indicate that the last packet has been sent.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained myself to well. I am some kind of a Gateway between the client and server, meaning that i can see all traffic passing between them. Now, a non-persistent HTTP connection  is established between the server and the client, the client sends a HTTP request and the server responses with a 200 OK and a file. The response doesn't contain the 'Content-Length' header. I , as the Gateway between them, want to know when the last packet is sent from the server before it reaches the client. Meaning, Waiting for the connection to close is not good for me.

Comment: If it's not sending the `Content-Length` header and it's not using something like chunked transfer encoding then I don't know of any other way to detect the last packet besides disconnection.